# Android 'busy spinner' (progress bar) not taking color

Tags: android, android-layout, android-progressbar

I have followed the example [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VmLXxCSxtds) to try to create a 'busy' spinning progress wheel.

The look of the spinner is defined in busy_spinner.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="90"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="360">

    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:tint="#0000FF"
        android:thicknessRatio="7.0">

        <gradient
            android:angle="0"
            android:centerColor="#0000FF"
            android:endColor="#9999FF"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false" />
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

and it is included in my layout file as follows:

```
 <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/working_bluebadgeparking_reachable"
                        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/busy_spinner" />
```

with visibility being switched on and off programatically and everything looks good except that the spinner is red!

As you can see in the busy_spinner.xml I have defined the spinner to be a nice blue gradient, but the color just isn't working.

Comment: This is on a Lollipop HTC One and in the emulator on the latest Nexus 5 Rom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the wrong property for a ProgressBar with indeterminate progress.

To set the drawable for indeterminate progress, use the [indeterminateDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#attr_android:indeterminateDrawable) property.  What you're doing is setting the drawable for determinate progress, which is typically a bar that progresses horizontally from 0 to 100%.